# Odoo 17: automation rule apply on Contact when create new

Tags: odoo, contacts

I've been testing Automation Rule with Odoo 17 as below configuation:

Model: Contact
Trigger: After creation
Actions To Do: Create activity and assign to defined user.

But when I create contact there is no activity created.
Are there any wrongs for this?

Please help me this case. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Could u add a screen shot please?